# Initialize react-native-firebase with web firebase configuration

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

is it possible to install react-native-firebase without touching the native code and use the js config of firebase to initialize react-native-firebase?

I think of something like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import RNfirebase from 'react-native-firebase'
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "someApiKey",
  authDomain: "some.auth.domain",
  databaseURL: "dbUrl",
  projectId: "myProjectId",
  storageBucket: "storage",
  messagingSenderId: "8734652304"
}
const myFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(config)
const myRNFirebaseRef = RNfirebase.initializeRNApp(myFirebase)
```

Or do i have to install it on the specific native platform?

In the documentation is a point to install/(use) it in 'web style'. But there is no description about how to use the 'main firebase configuration'.

Comment: You can use firebase instead of react-native-firebase. You won't need to install it on specific platform.

Comment: Of course you can use firebase with only JS, take a look at this [package](https://rnfirebase.io/)